# Conexão do MS Access e PHP

Tags: php, microsoft-access

Estou com um problema ao efetuar uma conexão com o MS Access e o PHP, esta dando um erro que não sei como arrumar, alguem poderia me ajudar ???

O código é este:

```
//Abre a conexão asdasda
$conn = new COM('ADODB.Connection') or die('ADO não iniciado');
//linha 30 

   $conn->Open('Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; 
   Data Source='.realpath('..\db\dashboard.accdb').'; 
   Persist Security Info=False;');

//fim da linha 30

//Pronto para utilizar o banco de dados

// Fecha a conexão
$conn->Close();
```

e o erro é este:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Linha 30 é a parte do $conn->Open toda?

Comment: Se sim tente trocar a parte do realpath('..\db\dashboard.accdb') para uma variavel e concatene a variavel na string para ver no que da e poste aqui o resultado

Comment: Ja consegui me conectar ao banco, não diretamente a ele, vinculei o Access a um banco msql e pego os dados atraves deste banco, precisava urgente dos dados e acabei fazendo desta forma, mas irei testar pela forma que você falou e posto o resultado aqui assim que der um tempo, vlw ai :)

Comment: conseguiu conectar, mas alterando o código, vou colocar ele aqui pois se alguém também estiver com dificuldade nisso já da uma ajuda

Comment: Para accdb, se não me engano, você deve instalar a versão 12 do MS JET. Já tive um problema com PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma solução é usar [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php), um exemplo:

```
// Add arquivo e a extensão 
$database_name = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "C:\..\..\..\..\arquivo.accbd"; 
// Check if file exist.
if (!file_exists($database_name )) {
    die("Não foi possível encontrar o arquivo.");
}
// Conecta o banco com o seu projeto.
$db = new PDO("odbc:DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)}; DBNAME=$database_name ; username=; password=;");

try {
     $db = new PDO("odbc:DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accbd)}; 
     DBNAME=$database_name ; username=; password=;");

     $db ->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
     echo "Sucesso"; 
}
catch(PDOException $e){
      echo "Falha na Conexão: " . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Isto é a solução?

Comment: para o meu erro ali foi, consegui conectar numa boa com esse codigo

Comment: É que fiquei sem entender se era solução ou se você postou outro código com problema. Recomendo que no futuro detalhe sempre que possivel a resposta, falando as tecnologias que usou, no caso usou a API chamada PDO. Pronto editei sua resposta e deixei um upvote +1

Comment: é que eu havia comentado ali em cima que iria postar o código, mas obrigado pela dica

Comment: Então, é que os campos de comentários são descartáveis, o legal é mesmo detalhar o minimo que puder a resposta, indicando por exemplo links para documentação. ;)